# Defining $Hom(f,W)$

Tags: category-theory, functors, hom-functor

Fix a field $k$ and a vector space $W$ over $k$. All other vector spaces will vector spaces over $k$ as well.

Given a linear map $f:V\to V'$, there is a linear map $f^\ast:Hom(V',W)\to Hom(V,W)$ defined by $f^\ast(\alpha)=\alpha\circ f$.

I've been trying to write the details of the proof that $Hom(-,W)$ is a functor $Vect_k^{op}\to Vect$. What confuses me is how to deal with $^{op}$ in proving the functoriality (and even defining $Hom(f,W)$ to begin with).

Let's write $F_W$ for $Hom(-,W)$. It's clear that $F_W$ assigns to each object of $Vect_k^{op}$ an object of $Vect_k$. I need to prove that $F_W$ assigns to each morphism $f: V\to V'$ in $Vect_k^{op}$ a morphism $F_W(f):Hom(V,W)\to Hom(V',W)$ in $Vect_k$ such that $F_W(1_V)=1_{Hom(V,W)}$ and $F_W(g\circ f)=F_W(g)\circ F_W(f)$ whenever $f:V\to V'$ and $g:V'\to V''$ are morphisms in $Vect_k^{op}$.

Let $f: V\to V'$  be a morphism in $Vect_k^{op}$. I know how to assign to it a morphism $Hom(V',W)\to Hom(V,W)$; but I need to assign to it a morphism $F_W(f):Hom(V,W)\to Hom(V',W)$. To this end I need to have a morphism $V'\to V$. But I only have a morphism $f: V\to V'$  in $Vect_k^{op}$. I do understand that it corresponds to a morphism $ V'\to V$  in $Vect_k$, but at this point we are only dealing with $Vect_k^{op}$, not with $Vect_k$. So at least how to define $F_W(f)$ formally, without having a morphism $V'\to V$?

---

Update:

Alright, so one assigns to an arrow $f\in Vect_k^{op}(V,V')=Vect_k(V',V)$ the arrow in $Vect_k(Hom(V,W),Hom(V',W))$ defined by $\alpha\mapsto \alpha\circ f$. But now I still have a problem with functoriality. Suppose $g\in Vect_k^{op}(V',V'')$. The corresponding arrow in $Vect_k(Hom(V',W),Hom(V'',W))$ is defined by $\beta\mapsto \beta\circ g$.

We need to show that $F_W(g\circ f)=F_W(g)\circ F_W(f)$.

Note that $(F_W(g)\circ F_W(f))(\alpha)=F_W(g)(\alpha\circ f)=\alpha\circ f\circ g$.

However, $F_W(g\circ f)(\alpha)=\alpha\circ g\circ f$.

What's wrong?

Update 2:

I think I see what's wrong. It's not true that $F_W(g\circ f)(\alpha)=\alpha\circ g\circ f$. The image of $F_W(g\circ f)$ is the map $\gamma\mapsto \gamma \circ \text{the arrow in the category } Vect_k(V'',V) \text{ corresponding to the arrow } g\circ f \text{ in the category } Vect_k(V,V'')=\gamma\circ f\circ g$

Comment: If $f:V\to V^\prime$ is a morphism in $Vect_k^{op}$ then it is also a morphism $V^\prime\to V$ in $Vect_k$.

Comment: @user634426 Your second update is correct: $F_W(g \circ_{op} f) = F_W(f\circ g) \equiv [\gamma \mapsto (\gamma \circ f\circ g)] = F_W(g)\circ F_W(f)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help to distinguish between composition $\circ$ in $\mathrm{Vect}_k$ and composition $\circ_{op}$ in $\mathrm{Vect}_k^{op}$. We can also distinguish by color: $\color{steelblue}{f, g}$ for objects in $\mathrm{Vect}_k$ and $\color{maroon}{f, g}$ for those same objects in $\mathrm{Vect}_k^{op}$.

Then if $f:V\rightarrow V^\prime$ and $g:V^\prime \rightarrow V^{\prime\prime}$, we can interchangeably refer to the composite either as $\color{steelblue}{(g\circ f)}$ in the original category or equivalently as $\color{maroon}{(f\circ_{op} g)}$ in the opposite category.

Functoriality comes from the fact that

$$F_W(\color{maroon}{f})\circ F_W(\color{maroon}{g}) \equiv [\alpha \mapsto (\alpha \circ g)\circ f] = [\alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ \color{steelblue}{(g \circ f)}] = [\alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ \color{maroon}{(f\circ_{op} g)}] = F_W(\color{maroon}{f\circ_{op} g})$$

Comment: But what's wrong with my updated "proof"? I think I started with the opposite category right away. And one of my results ($F_W(g\circ f)(\alpha)=\alpha\circ g\circ f$) is the same as yours (I used $F_W$ instead of your "star notation"). But $F_W(g)\circ F_W(f)(\alpha)$ doesn't match with that result, even though I regarded $f$ and $g$ as arrows in the opposite category.

Comment: The bug is that we have to distinguish two different notions of composition: $F_W(g) \circ F_W(f) = [\alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ f \circ g]$. And $F_W(g\circ_{op} f) \equiv F_W(f\circ g) = [\alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ (f\circ g)] = [\alpha \mapsto \alpha\circ f \circ g]$. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to repeat some of what you wrote with more words to get myself up to speed.

Let's write $V^{op}$ for the object in ${Vect}_k^{op}$ that corresponds to the vector space $V$  and $f^{op}$ for the arrow in ${Vect}_k^{op}$ corresponding to the linear map $f$.

So, given $f^{op}\colon B^{op} \to A^{op}$, $F_W(f^{op}) = Hom(f,W)$ should be an arrow $Hom(B,W) \to Hom(A,W)$. So how do I take a linear map $\alpha\colon B\to W$ and turn it into one $A \to W$? Well, precompose with $f\colon A \to B$, the linear map that $f^{op}$ corresponds to!

---

Now how should composition work? The fact that you're working with *opposite* categories tells me that when we say "functor" we really only ever mean "covariant functor." So it should be true that $F_W(f^{op}g^{op}) = F_W(f^{op})F_W(g^{op}) = F_W([gf]^{op}) = Hom(gf,W) = Hom(g,W)\circ Hom(f,W)$.

And indeed, if given $g \colon B \to C$ and $\alpha\colon C \to W$, I precompose $(\alpha g)\colon B \to W$ with $f\colon A \to B$, I get a morphism $\alpha gf$ in $Hom(A,W)$.

Note that it is **emphatically** not the case that both compositions make sense. This is why I have insisted on superscripting "op" everywhere just for clarity.

Comment: Passing to the next step, if there are $f\in Vect_k^{op}(V,V')=Vect_k(V',V)$ and $g\in Vect_k^{op}(V',V'')=Vect_k(V'',V')$, how do I know which of the two equalities to prove (to establish functoriality): $F_W(g\circ f)=F_W(g)\circ F_W(f)$ or $F_W(f\circ g)=F_W(f)\circ F_W(g)$? Both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ make sense as compositions.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some thoughts.

Comment: Do you mean that $g^{op}\in Vect_k^{op}(V',V'')$ and $f^{op}\in Vect_k^{op}(V,V')$? If so, then how does the composition $f^{op}\circ g^{op}$ make sense? I've added some details in the question as well.

Comment: I mean that $f\colon V \to V'$ and $g\colon V' \to V''$, so that $gf \colon V \to V''$. Thus $(gf)^{op} \colon V''^{op} \to V^{op}$. Indeed $g^{op}\colon V''^{op} \to V'{op}$, and $f^{op}\colon V'^{op} \to V^{op}$, so $(gf)^{op} = f^{op}\circ g^{op}$.

Comment: If $f:V\to V'$ and $g:V'\to V''$, then it makes sense. But your answer says that $f:V'\to V$ and $g: V''\to V'$.

Comment: Sorry, I switched notation midway in my answer. I'll update everything away from $V$s for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the update! But I believe there is still something wrong: if $g:C\to B$, then $g^{op}: B^{op}\to C^{op}$. At the same time $f^{op}:A^{op}\to B^{op}$, so $f^{op}g^{op}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: aaaaargh you are right again. switching back and forth is too confusing for me. What I would like to say is that $f\colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to C$, so that $g^{op} \colon C^{op} \to B^{op}$ can be followed by $f^{op}\colon B^{op} \to A^{op}$.

Comment: Why do you write $F_W(f^{op})=Hom(f,W)$? When I introduced this notation, I thought $F_W(-)$ is synonymous to $Hom(-,W)$. Why does $^{op}$ disappear then?

Comment: $F_W$ is a *covariant* functor from ${Vect}^{op}_k$ to ${Vect}_k$. $Hom(-,W)$, as written, would be a *contravariant* functor from ${Vect}_k$ to itself. It doesn't make sense to talk about $Hom(V^{op},W)$.

Comment: Why would $Hom(-,W)$ be contravariant? Leinster claims at the bottom of p.23 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) that $Hom(-,W)$ is a covariant functor from $Vect_k^{op}$ to $Vect_k$.

Comment: I meant the assignment $V \mapsto Hom(V,W)$ would be contravariant, since the order of arrows are reversed as you can see.